# Finding element by "data-reactid" on Yahoo! Finance

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am writing a python program to evaluate stock prices. I'm using [this page on Yahoo! finance](https://finance.yahoo.com/screener/predefined/day_gainers) to get my stock informaiton. I want to be able to get the top five listings' **stock symbol** on the top gainers page.

Can someone either provide me with an example of how to get the top five stock **symbols** or show me how I can find the symbol element(using the data-reactid or any other meathod) using selenium preferably.

Before this is flagged as a copy, I looked at the pages similar to this, but they did not solve my problem. Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I personally don't have a lot of experience with Selenium, but this sounds like a job that could be handled with either [BeatifulSoup's find()/findall()](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#calling-a-tag-is-like-calling-find-all) methods, or with [scrapy's Xpath/ CSS selectors](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html).

For a beginner, I would recommend BeautifulSoup for a task like this. it makes it easy to target the page element you're looking for (in this case the stock symbol w/ data-reactid).

Hope this helped.

Comment: I will probably end up using BeautifulSoup. Thanks